# output prime numbers in Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, initialization, boolean, primes, fibonacci

Can someone please check my code. I am having trouble extracting the prime number within the loop.  If the user enters 5, the output should be : 2 3 5 13 89  and if the user enters 7, the output should be 2 3 5 13 89 233 1597 , etc,

```
 countPrime= int(0)
 endNum= int(0)
 a0= int(0)
 a1= int(1)
 checkPrime= False
 valueN= int(input("Enter the value of N: \n"))

 while (countPrime < valueN): 
      endNum= a0 + a1
      a0= a1
      a1= endNum

      for i in range(2, endNum+1):                   # prime check 
           if (not endNum % i ==0 and endNum > 2):       #
                checkPrime= True                         #

      if(checkPrime==True):
          countPrime+=1   
          print(endNum, end=" ")
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting or problem you're having? Also, the body of your while loop isn't indented. Using correct grammar will help with communication a lot, too.

Comment: Saying "*please I need assistance urgently*" will not help you anywhere near as much as having a clearly worded question with a good description of the problem and proper formatting.

Comment: Ignore the indentation , i made a mistake when copying and pasting it here. When i run the code, the prime Fibonacci sequence does not display , instead the original Fibonacci sequence is displayed

Comment: Your indentation still doesn't make sense. Presumably you want your `for` loop and `if(checkPrime==True)` block to be executed for each iteration of the `while` loop, in which case they need to be indented to the same level as the `while` block.

Comment: sorry guys i did not realize  there were errors with indentation , i corrected it now ( pasted incorrectly)

Comment: No, it's still not fixed yet - `checkPrime= True` needs to be indented further, since it comes after an `if` statement

Comment: okay now you can check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The while loop is not indented.

If it was, it would calculate just the Nth Fibonacci number.

And in the for loop, looks like you set checkPrime= True if the number is indivisible by *some* number, which would always be the case.

Comment: OK but your prime check is still "backwards", it's flagged as prime if there's any number it's not divisible by. Plus you don't reset the checkPrime within the loop.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to upload this code a long time ago

```
countPrime= int(0)
checkPrime=True     
endNum= int(0)      
prevNum= int(0)         
nextNum= int(1)         
valueN= int(input("Enter the value of N: \n"))   
print("\nThe Prime numbers are: ")

def checkIfPrime(endNum):              
     sumFact=0                         
     for i in range(1, endNum+1):       
          if(endNum % i == 0):         
               sumFact+=1             
     if(sumFact==2):                   
          return True
     else:
          return False
while (countPrime < valueN):
     endNum= prevNum + nextNum        
     prevNum= nextNum                
     nextNum= endNum                  
     checkPrime= checkIfPrime(endNum)     
     if(checkPrime==True):                
          countPrime+=1                   
          checkPrime= False               
          print(endNum," ", end=" ")
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code uses recursion to output the Fibonacci sequence using recursion:

```
sequence=[0,1]
def fibonacci(num,prev, after):
    if(len(sequence) !=num):       # base case
        nextNum = prev +after           # change of state
        sequence.append(nextNum)
        fibonacci(num,after,nextNum)     # function calls itself
    return sequence

print(fibonacci(10,0,1))  # test with 10 numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

**This technique makes use of the "*tuple*" data type :**

```
def fibonacci(n):
 a,b = 1,1
 for i in range(n-1):
 a,b = b,a+b
 return a
print fibonacci(5)      # test with 5 numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using *classes* you can do this :**

```
class Fibo:
 def __init__(self, fn):
  self.fn = fn
  self.memo = {}
 def __call__(self, arg):
  if arg not in self.memo:
   self.memo[arg] = self.fn(arg)
   return self.memo[arg]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Bjorn Munch noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29583852/674064), your prime check doesn't do what it's supposed to. Could you have noticed that yourself? With you current code that might have been difficult. But if you pull out separate concerns into separate functions, they can be individually tested and verified:

```
import unittest

def is_prime(number):
    for divisor in range(2, number+1):
        if (not number % divisor == 0 and number > 2):
            return True
    return False

class TestIsPrime(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_0_isnt_prime(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_prime(0))

    def test_1_isnt_prime(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_prime(1))

    def test_2_is_prime(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_prime(2))

    def test_3_is_prime(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_prime(3))

    def test_4_isnt_prime(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_prime(4))

    def test_23_is_prime(self):
        self.assertTrue(is_prime(23))

    def test_25_isnt_prime(self):
        self.assertFalse(is_prime(25))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running this would have given you:

```
...FF.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_25_isnt_prime (__main__.TestIsPrime)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fibprime.py", line 29, in test_25_isnt_prime
    self.assertFalse(is_prime(25))
AssertionError: True is not false

======================================================================
FAIL: test_2_is_prime (__main__.TestIsPrime)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fibprime.py", line 17, in test_2_is_prime
    self.assertTrue(is_prime(2))
AssertionError: False is not true

======================================================================
FAIL: test_4_isnt_prime (__main__.TestIsPrime)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fibprime.py", line 23, in test_4_isnt_prime
    self.assertFalse(is_prime(4))
AssertionError: True is not false

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=3)
```

Comment: You're welcome @JeshenAppanna. To challenge myself, I've tried to pluck your code completely into functions and to cover them with automated tests. If you're interested in the result, please let me know and I'll post it with some beginner-friendly explanations.